# OnVScroll : invoked from CSpinButtonCtrl or Vertical ScrollBar?

Tags: c++, mfc, scrollbar

I have a derived MFC `CFormView` class (`CMyFormView`) and I must implement my own `OnVScroll` function.

My `CMyFormView` is used for several dialog box resources, mainly, to re-implement the `OnCtlColor()` function. Some dialogs contain a `CSpinButtonCtrl` control.

**My problem:**
When the `OnVScroll` function is invoked, I am unable to know if the Windows message comes from a `CSpinButtonCtrl` or from the scrollbar.

```
void CMyFormView :: OnVScroll (UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar * pScrollBar)
{
// message comes from CSpinButtonCtrl or VscrollBare ?
}
```

I cannot use the `CSpinButtonCtrl` IDs (*dlgitem*) of the controls because they are very numerous.

**Question:**
How to know if the message comes from a `CSpinButtonCtrl` or the scrollbar?

**Environment details:**

- Windows 7
- Visual studio 2010
- MFC

Comment: @AdrianMole i use the default scroll bare, i dont add manually my own scroll bare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `OnVScroll` handler is called *via* actions in a window's (framework-provided) scrollbar, then the `pScrollBar` parameter will be `NULL`; if it is from a control, then it will not be `NULL`. From the [CWnd Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#onvscroll):

> *pScrollBar*
>  If the scroll message came from a scroll-bar control, contains a pointer to the control. If the user clicked a
>   window's scroll bar, this parameter is NULL. The pointer may be
>   temporary and should not be stored for later use.

So, you can simply check for a `NULL` value:

```cpp
void CMyFormView :: OnVScroll (UINT nSBCode, UINT nPos, CScrollBar * pScrollBar)
{
    if (!pScrollBar) {
        // From window's scrollbar...
    }
    else {
        // From a control...
    }
}
```